# singleLine true for Textview,But multiple lines comes in one line..,Need to show 1st line

Tags: android

Given singleLine="true" for Textview

```
 msg = messageInbox.getMESSAGE();
msg = msg.replaceAll("\n", "<br/>");
descView.setText(Html.fromHtml(msg));
```

Text does not displaying with Only 1st line .
example i have test \n\n\n and more \n
i need to display 1st line test

Comment: By giving singleLine=true , will prevent TextView from printing the extra lines apart from first line. So texts after "\n"  or "<br>" will not show at all

Comment: I am getting this responce ** "Message":"test\nmore\n\n\n\n----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n** I need to show 1st line test  where i have given single line true for that textview

Comment: finally solved thanks to all who replied ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (msg.contains("\n"))
      msg = msg.substring(0, msg.indexOf("\n"));
 else
      msg = msg.replaceAll("\n", "<br/>");
```

Answer (score 0):

try this textview attributes

```
android:inputType="textPersonName"
```

OR

```
android:maxLines="1"
```

Comment: i checked with the both , but no output.